# Sharing/Proxying CodeIgniter Sessions across multiple CI instances on the same domain

Tags: session, codeigniter, proxy

I've got the following setup:

```
Site1 (Core) at Core.example.com
Site2 (Work1) at Work1.example.com
Site3 (Work2) at Work2.example.com
```

etc... I'll just user `Work1` in discussion but the problem applies to all the `Work` sites

The idea is that `Core` is used for logins, payments, account management, etc and the Work sites offer functionality which is sufficiently different to justify separate CI instances/Dbs/etc.

This works relativfely well in that `Core` can set cookies which are picked up by the other sites.

The issue I've got is that I want to allow eg `Work1` to make calls to `Core` on behalf of the user/as the user - for things like updating user account details, getting a list of services available to the user, etc.

I'm currently trying to do this via CURL. If I read the `Core` session cookie in the HTTP request made by the client to `Work1` and inject it into the CURL request from `Work1` to `Core`, `Core` doesn't accept it as a valid session cookie. I'm not sure if this is due to differing IP addresses (Client vs `Work1`) or something else.

Unfortunately, I need `Work1` to have its own database so sharing a DB is not a viable option. That said, I've used the same encryption key across the sites so can decrypt/parse cookies (or anything else) as required on any site.

Can someone please suggest how I can convince `Core` that a request from `Worker1` with the users' `Core` session cookie is in fact from the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was eventually able to work around this by reading to cookie and injecting it into curl requests. I also had to handle session cookie updates retrieved via CURL, re-wrap them and pass them back to the client.

I also extended the IP verification to check the the session IP is Either: the client IP for the current request OR is my Work1 site's IP address and the HTTPS request has a `MySite-OriginalIp` header (which is attached to all my CURL requests) and that this value matches the session.

There are a number of other security enhancements, tweaks and sanity checks that are required to get this going in a robust and reliable way without compromising security - Too many to detail here.